# My render method in react will not let me filter my data from an axios call and null check doesnt work. Seems Like an easy fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, redux, axios

I have a large list of data that I get from an axios call, and I want to be able to do a quick filter to filter my data and only show what is included in the search bar. For some reason when I try to set my props to a variable then filter through it, I says that it is undefined. So I tried to do a simple null check and then do my js but it still doesn't work. I think part of the issue is the time at which the data is getting called in and the render method doing the filtering to quickly? Thanks in advance!

```
class App extends Component {

   constructor(){
     super();
     this.state={
       filteredData: null,
       input: ''
     };
   }

   componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.GetAllData();
   }

   onChange=(txt)=>{
     this.setState({input: txt});
   }

   render() {

     const filteredData = !!this.props.people ? this.props.people.filter(card =>{
        return card.name.toUpperCase.includes(this.state.input.toUpperCase())
        }) : null

   return(

    <SearchBar cards={this.props.people} inputTxt={this.onChange}/>
    {!!this.props.people ? this.props.people.map(i => <Card person={i} key={i.created}/>) : null}
)
   }
```

Comment: `componentWillMount = () => {` should just be `componentWillMount() {`. It's a method on the class not a property.

Comment: Also you should be using `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Also if you have class fields enabled, there's no reason to use constructor. Just do `state = {` right on the class like your other fields.

Comment: Also `toUpperCase` is a method so it should be `card.name.toUpperCase().includes`

Comment: Also you can't return to children in React's render. Those need to be wrapped in a `<div>` or a [`<Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Comment: What are you using `filteredData` for? It looks to be a filtered version of `this.props.people`, but then it's never used; `this.props.people` is always still used in your render.